# Apollo GraphQL Deprecation Warnings

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am getting lots of deprecation warnings. I am not sure why I am getting it. Could anyone please guide me out.

I have created a boilerplate for apollo graph ql with koa node js frameworks. I am planning to use a graph ql subscription in my next project. However, these warnings or errors making me confused. this is my git https://github.com/sumitbhavra/graphql-koa.git

```
{
          "name": "include",
          "description": "Directs the executor to include this field or fragment only when the `if` argument is true.",
          "locations": [
            "FIELD",
            "FRAGMENT_SPREAD",
            "INLINE_FRAGMENT"
          ],
          "args": [
            {
              "name": "if",
              "description": "Included when true.",
              "type": {
                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                "name": null,
                "ofType": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "Boolean",
                  "ofType": null
                }
              },
              "defaultValue": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "deprecated",
          "description": "Marks an element of a GraphQL schema as no longer supported.",
          "locations": [
            "FIELD_DEFINITION",
            "ENUM_VALUE"
          ],
          "args": [
            {
              "name": "reason",
              "description": "Explains why this element was deprecated, usually also including a suggestion for how to access supported similar data. Formatted using the Markdown syntax, as specified by [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/).",
              "type": {
                "kind": "SCALAR",
                "name": "String",
                "ofType": null
              },
              "defaultValue": "\"No longer supported\""
            }
          ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a deprecation warning. That is an introspection result that includes information about the `@deprecated` directive, which can be used inside your type definitions to mark individual fields or enum values as deprecated.